# ASP, My SQL & case sensitity suddenly broken

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

We have an old ASPsite that has been working fine for years with a MY SQL database. All of a sudden last week lots fo SQL queries stopped working.

The database has a table called 'members' but the code calls 'Members'. It appears the queries used to work regardless of case sensitivity on the table names, but something has changed recently somewhere to enforce case.

This has me stumped as the site has not been touched in years, the server config hasn't changed & the database provide has not changed anything.

Is there any simple way to ignore case for an ASP site (without editing lots fo files :)

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Did you move the database server to a Linux machine?

Comment: "as the site has not been touched in years, the server config hasn't changed & the database provide has not changed anything."  <-- Clearly something changed, or you wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page from the manual to learn about [case-sensitivity and identifiers in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Someone may have switched the `lower_case_table_names` toggle, or (as webdestroya comments) moved the database server from a case-insensitive OS (e.g. Windows) to a case-sensitive OS (e.g. Linux).

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the tip, I will talk to the ISP more, tehir initial comment was that nothing had moved or changed but i agree, they must have doen something!

Comment: So my horrible host 'Fasthosts' are claiming nothing at all has changed.

I've solved this by moving the database to a MySQL instance running from an existing Windos box :)  A bit of a cheat but it works.